# Dropdown with flags in Vuejs

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I want to do a dropdown with flags for phone numbers in a form using Vuejs but I didn't found a solution. I tried all the solutions in the internet using html and css but no result and I tried also the vuejs solution flag-dropdown-vue but the installation always give me errors please any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: If you install it as a Vue.js dependency (https://www.npmjs.com/package/flags-dropdown-vue), then you should be able to use the component. But we can't help if we don't know what steps you have taken.

Comment: @dinarobert I added an answer. Hope it will work as per your requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply achieve this with [`vue-select`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-select) package.

Live Demo **:**

```js
Vue.component('v-select', VueSelect.VueSelect);

new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   data: {
      options: [
         { value: 'AF', label: 'Afghanistan'},
         { value: 'AX', label: 'Aland Islands'},
         { value: 'AL', label: 'Albania'},
         { value: 'DZ', label: 'Algeria'},
         { value: 'AS', label: 'American Samoa'}
      ]
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.7.13/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-select@2.6.4/dist/vue-select.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flag-icon-css/0.8.2/css/flag-icon.min.css"/>
<div id="app">
   <v-select :options="options">
      <template slot="option" slot-scope="option">
         <span class="flag-icon flag-icon-squared" :class="['flag-icon-' + option.value.toLowerCase()]"></span>
         <span class="flag-text">{{ option.label }}</span>
      </template>
   </v-select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but the only problem is that vuejs don't accept two scripts tag. I don't know how to add those script

Comment: @dinarobert What do you mean by - *vuejs don't accept two scripts tag* ?

Comment: when I added your code inside my template it shows this error : VueCompilerError: Tags with side effect (<script> and <style>) are ignored in client component templates. And if I ussed it outside the template it give me this error : VueCompilerError: Single file component can contain only one <script> element

Comment: @dinarobert Just for a demo in the stackoverflow editor, I used these two script tags but in your actual production or development environment you can include these libraries as a dependency by using npm or you can also use cdn link in your app global file.